# Different colors for edges of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to make a tcolorbox where the right border is blue and the top border is green, but can't seem to find any options online or in the manuals for individual line colors. Is this possible?

Comment: You can draw the frame by yourself using `tcolorbox` options `geometry nodes, frame code={<tikz code making use of node "frame">}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library `skins` to add individual borders on every side of the box; see chapter 10 in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Here's a small example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0mm,
    enhanced,
    borderline north={2pt}{0pt}{green},
    borderline east={2pt}{0pt}{blue},
]
A box with a blue right border and a green top border.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```